How to add css style with tailwind in Reactjs
What is the equivalent of this code below in Tailwind :
<span style ="--i:1;">Some Text is here</span>
<span style ="--i:2;">Some Text is here</span>


Tailwind doesn't natively support custom CSS properties directly within its utility classes. However, you can add custom properties by extending the framework or adding styles manually
You can keep the --i custom property inline and use Tailwind utility classes for other styling:
<span style="--i:1;" class="text-base text-gray-700">Some Text is here</span>
<span style="--i:2;" class="text-base text-gray-700">Some Text is here</span>

If you're using a recent version of Tailwind (v2.2+), you can set custom properties using arbitrary values:
<span class="[--i:1] text-base text-gray-700">Some Text is here</span>
<span class="[--i:2] text-base text-gray-700">Some Text is here</span>

